# Algorithm to call a function inside a function argument in javascript

Tags: javascript, function

here is my code problem, There are three arguments in my function `x , y` and `num`. `num` must be multiplied with `x` and `y` and return.

```js
function abc(num, x, y) {
  return num * x + " " + num * y;
}

console.log(   
  abc(5, 2, 4) //returns 10 20
);

console.log(
  abc(5, abc(5, 6, 6), 4) //doesn't return 30 30 20 
)

function abc1(num, x, y) {
  if (isNaN(x)) {
    return x + " " + y * num; //now it returns 30 30 20 for abc(5,abc(5,6,6),4)
  }
  return num * x + " " + num * y;
}

console.log(   
  abc1(5, 2, 4) //returns 10 20
);

console.log(
  abc1(5, abc(5, 6, 6), 4) //now it returns 30 30 20 for abc(5,abc(5,6,6),4)
)
```

I also want to know how to achieve if I call the function below (function inside the argument of the same function)-

```
abc(5,abc(abc(5,abc(5,6,6),abc(5,abc(5,6,6),4)))) // it must return something like how abc(5,abc(5,6,6),4) should return 30 30 20
```

I want when I call the function `abc(5,2,abc(5,abc(5,4,4),3))` should return all parameters(except `num`) every time  like `10 20 20 15` for calling the function - `abc(5,2,abc(5,abc(5,4,4),3))` if I place the same function in the function Parameter/arguments.

I tried but when I call the function inside the same function arguments like `abc(5,abc(5,6,6),4)` the `x` in the `function abc(num,x,y)` becomes `NaN` hence returns like `NaN 20` but not `30 30 20`.

but how to do for this `abc(5,abc(abc(5,abc(5,6,6),abc(5,abc(5,6,6),4))))` to return the same way like above.

Any online source would help, Thanks.

Comment: why `30 30 20` for `abc(5,abc(5,6,6),4)` and not `[150, 150, 20]`?

Comment: What is it supposed to do when you pass the result of `abc` as first parameter of another `abc` call?

Comment: thanks for commenting, btw I achieved the first one function ```abc1(num, x, y) {
  if (isNaN(x)) {
    return x + " " + y * num; //now it returns 30 30 20 for abc(5,abc(5,6,6),4)
  }
  return num * x + " " + num * y;
}```

Comment: Your arguments are numbers and your function is returning strings. And you want to use the same function as an argument (that returns a string) which should be a number. I wouldn't do that.

Comment: I can convert to string and by the use of regex i can achieve but, I think that is very tedious, there must be an answer in function closure.  Thanks for commenting everybody.

Comment: You are expecting number inputs, yet abc is returning a string, so then feeding itself as input will not work. Hard time to grasp what you are trying to solve, but I have vibes you shouldn't be doing these at all. Maybe return arrays and process arrays, or something. I would say whatever you are trying there is a better paradigm for it, just I do not really get what you are trying to do

Comment: Don't use regex on this

Comment: do you really need a string as result?

Comment: @AntonKrug, there is no recursion here. the function does not call itself.

Comment: @AntonKrug, why not to use regex what's wrong in it.

Comment: @AbhinashMajhi because most likely it's just working around a problem, that it has probably wrong types. Nina provided a good solution with arrays and you can still make toString function to convert it into a string. I mean nothing is stopping you to use regex but it might pretty heavy, slow and wrong way around the problem. If you want you could implement in the magic the gathering play cards as that is Turing complete, but how efficient that would be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could return an array and check if the value is an array and use the values instead of multiplying with the given factor.

```js
function fn(f, a, b) {
    return [
        ...(Array.isArray(a) ? a : [f * a]),
        ...(Array.isArray(b) ? b : [f * b]),
    ];
}

console.log(...fn(5, 6, 6));                     // [30, 30]
console.log(...fn(5, fn(5, 6, 6), 4));           // [30, 30, 20]
console.log(...fn(5, 2, fn(5, fn(5, 4, 4), 3))); // [10, 20, 20, 15]
```

An even shorter approach

```js
function fn(f, ...values) {
    return values.flatMap(x => Array.isArray(x) ? x : [f * x]);
}

console.log(...fn(5, 6, 6));                     // [30, 30]
console.log(...fn(5, fn(5, 6, 6), 4));           // [30, 30, 20]
console.log(...fn(5, 2, fn(5, fn(5, 4, 4), 3))); // [10, 20, 20, 15]
```